# How to color background on Chrome browser console with Javascript

Tags: google-chrome, console.log

If I use `console.warn` or `console.error` the whole line background is colored respectively in yellow and red.

However if I want to color the background with `console.log` it seems it is not possible with simple CSS commands.

I was wondering if there are other methods to achieve that.

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```js
console.log('%c%s', 'background-color: purple;', 'Lorem ipsum (something) else: {}');
console.warn('Lorem ipsum (something) else: {}');
console.error('Lorem ipsum (something) else: {}');
```

In this screenshot you can see the difference:

[image: different background colors for console]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.warn("%cThis is a warning with white text and purple background", "color:white; background-color: purple");
```

Comment: Thank you but not what I needed. This is coloring a warning. I need to color console.log filling the whole white background.